# How to make the index from ngFor part of an html tag value

Tags: angular

I have an `ngFor` loop set up like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let record of this.RecordsProcessed; let i = index">
   <div class="row my-16" data-test='test'_{{i}}>
        <div class="col-4">Id:</div>
        <div class="col-8">{{record?.Id}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to put the index from `ngFor` on the data-text tag within the html. Is it possible to do something like this within the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
  <div *ngFor="let record of this.RecordsProcessed; let i = index">
  <div class="row my-16" [attr.data-test]="'test_' + i">
       <div class="col-4">Id:</div>
       <div class="col-8">{{record?.Id}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[] brackets let angular know that everything inside of "" is typescript code.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, and the the explanation of the [] brackets makes sense. I wasn't thinking of that.